# How to cluster raw events tables from Firebase Analytics in BQ in field event_name?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I would like to cluster raw table with raw data of events from Firebase in BQ, but without reprocessing/creating another tables (keeping costs at minimum). 
The main idea is to find a way to cluster tables when they create from intraday table.

I tried to create empty tables with pre-defined schema (same as previous events tables), but partitioned by `_partition_time` column (NULL partition) and clustered by `event_name` column.

After Firebase inserts all the data from intraday table, the column `event_name` stays in details tab of table as cluster field, but no reducing costs happens after querying.

What could be another solution or way how to make it working ?

Thanks in advance.

/edit:
Our table has detail tab as:
[detail tab of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOSmU.png)

After running this query:

`SELECT * FROM 'ooooooo.ooooooo_ooooo.events_20181222'
WHERE event_name = 'screen_view'`

the result is:
[how query processed whole table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Fp2.png)

So no cost reducing.

But if I try to create the same table clustered by event_name manually with:

`Create TABLE 'aaaa.aaaa.events_20181222'
partition by DATE(event_timestamp)
cluster by event_name
AS
Select * from  ooooooo.ooooooo_ooooo.events_20181222`

Then the same query from first IMG applied to created table processes only 5mb - so clustering really works.

Comment: I asked similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980953/bigquery-cluster-field-usage-value-not-clear. Hope it can help. Please provide screenshot or any other detail which can help understand this better.

Comment: Your solution looks ok, can you post screenshot of your query to see what happens and why no reducing is happening? You might miss something there or wrong order of params.

Comment: Hi guys, @TamirKlein - real cost of processing is same as that from dryRun, but really appreciate your respond :)

Comment: @Pentium10 - I editted first post and added screenshots

Comment: I suggest you also check the execution plan (It's the detail tab next to the result) and compare again between the 2 tables

Comment: Good idea, I checked it - in table with pre-defined schema and data inserted automatically by firebase:
`Bytes Processed 11.3 MB
Bytes Billed 12.0 MB`

With table manually created with same data and clustered...
`Bytes Processed 6.36 MB
Bytes Billed 10.0 MB`

No idea, why it doesn't work.
Can it be made by some non-standard way of inserting data to that table ?

Comment: @DávidKadlub your table is damn small. BQ is designed for large data sets, don't expect on this small scale to get true clustering benefits. Try loading several gigabytes and should work.