# Bigquery clustering not reducing query costs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Im having an issue with clustered tables in BigQuery (with date partitions). I have a table that is clustered by a column named **entity_id**. The thing is, i expect to see a bytes read reduction when making queries filtered by these clustered column, but according with the BigQuery Web UI it's doing a fullscan anyway.

For example:
SELECT * FROM `project.usersDataset.users_cluster` WHERE **entity_id = '405849241'** LIMIT 1000;
Returns:
"Query complete (0.570 sec elapsed, **862.94 MB** processed)"
This is actually the full table size (**862,94 MB**)

This is the table configuration:
[Table configuration img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8axG.png)

EDIT: I keep going on tests and i found that sometimes, some bytes read are saved, but not too much:
[Query from BigQuery Web Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEV4v.png)
I was expecting a bigger amount of bytes cost to be saved (returned 1 entry and scanned 719MB of 862MB of the table) but nothing guaranteed these in the bigquery documentation.

Does anyone have a clue on what could be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: I asked a similar question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980953/bigquery-cluster-field-usage-value-not-clear, Can you also provide same screenshot from your web UI to help get to the bottom of this

Comment: Clustering is working only on partition tables, and kicks in generally above 1GB of data sets.

Comment: Yes Tamir, it's quite similar to your problem. Actually (as i edited the post recently) i continue testing and i found that sometimes some bytes cost reduction is been made (719MB of 862MB of the total table and returned 1 row). I suppose i was expecting a bigger cost save, but nothing guaranteed these in the bigquery documentation and as Pentium10 points out maybe the amount of data doesn't help neither. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

From BigQuery documentation provided in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)

> Features under development
>
> Support for clustering non-partitioned tables.

Please check you table is cluster and partition

Note: Cluster will also be used when no `WHERE` condition per BigQuery documentation

Comment: I forgot to add, it's a partitioned by date table clustered by entity_id field. I have recently edited the post to add the table specs. I have a doubt about your note, i thought you actually need the clustered field in the query for this to work

Comment: Check Felipe great article about cluster https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b see in his example the where part is on the partition only and how the cluster saves cost, this was my intention sorry if it wasn't clear. Hope this document will solve your issue.

Comment: @MarcoLotto, I posted another question on a similar issue which you can find in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209597/1031958). Note if you have a streaming buffer attach to your table you might need to run a daily `merge` command to see cost improvments