# Why the cost of a query on today cluster/partition is much higher than on previous dates?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partition/cluster table as follow:

[image]

When I run this query:

```
SELECT
  projectId
FROM
  `projectId.dataset.tables`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= "2019-03-16 00:00:00" AND _PARTITIONTIME <= "2019-03-17 00:00:00" 
  AND projectId='myproject' 
GROUP BY
  projectId
limit 1
```

I see an actual scan of **597 MB**

[image]

However, When I run the same query on the previous day as follow:

```
SELECT
  projectId
FROM
  `projectId.dataset.tables`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= "2019-03-15 00:00:00" AND _PARTITIONTIME <= "2019-03-16 00:00:00" 
  AND projectId='myproject' 
GROUP BY
  projectId
limit 1
```

I see an actual scan of **122 MB**

[image]

Note: The results are even worse if I add more columns.

To make sure my partition has the same size I counted the number of projectId in each partition

```
SELECT _partitionTime as date, count(projectId) as count
FROM
  `projectId.dataset.tables`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= "2019-03-15 00:00:00" AND _PARTITIONTIME <= "2019-03-17 00:00:00" 
GROUP BY
  date
```

And as you can see today partition has even fewer rows than the previous 2 days

[image]

In addtion I tried to query the streaming buffer using this query which returned no result

```
SELECT projectId FROM `projectId.dataset.tables`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL
```

My conclusion is that **the streaming buffer is impacting the cost of the query on a cluster table** but I'm not sure how can that be and why.

Any ideas on what is going on here and why do I see higher cost when querying today partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cluster a table, you're basically choosing how to physically sort it while stored.

When you stream into a table, new rows are stored roughly in the order received, hence breaking the "physically sorted" promise of clustering.

BigQuery should be smart enough to silently re-order your clustered tables once in a while, but if that process has not run, you won't see the benefits of clustering.

According to the currently published documentation, you can force a re-clustering of unsorted data with `MERGE`:

> Over time, as more and more operations modify a table, the degree to which the data is sorted begins to weaken, and the table becomes partially sorted. In a partially sorted table, queries that use the clustering columns may need to scan more blocks compared to a table that is fully sorted. You can re-cluster the data in the entire table by running a SELECT * query that selects from and overwrites the table (or any specific partition in it). In addition, any arbitrary portion of the table can be re-clustered using a DML MERGE statement.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables

Comment: Felipe as always thank you, I'm not sure I fully understand your answer. Are you saying that during the streaming the data is not being stored per the table cluster definition and bigquery run a batch job to build the cluster offline? If so why the clustering will weaken? Also don't you feel its a bit of a drawback if today partition is not optimized near insert / near real time as this is typically the most scannable partition?

Comment: The answer to that is that both things can't happen at the same time. At least under current implementation levels. Please note that clustering is in beta state today.

Comment: And it's too costly to keep reclustering all the data in the partition when the partition is actively being streamed into, like reclustering 500MB in the partition whenever 1MB is added to the partition by streaming extraction.

Answer (score 2):

Update: now BigQuery performs [automatic re-clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#automatic_re-clustering) on all clustered tables.