# How to view BigQuery streaming data information

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery which I constantly stream data into.

Since Bigquery clustering is not updated during the insert as advised by @Felipe as an answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209597/1031958) I want to run a `Merge` command on the table to force the build of the cluster.

However, when I do this I get this error

> UPDATE or DELETE statement over table projectId.datasetId.Jobs would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported

This is an example of the `merge` command I tried to use:

```
MERGE
    `projectId.datasetId.Jobs` as tgt
USING (SELECT *, _PARTITIONTIME FROM `projectId.datasetId.Jobs` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NOT NULL) as src

ON
    FALSE
WHEN
    NOT MATCHED AND src._PARTITIONTIME = '2019-04-01 00:00:00'
THEN
  INSERT (
      _PARTITIONTIME,    
       ts,     

  )
  VALUES (
      _PARTITIONTIME,    
       ts,     
  )  
WHEN
  NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND tgt._PARTITIONTIME = '2019-04-01 00:00:00' AND tgt._PARTITIONTIME IS NOT NULL
THEN
  DELETE
```

So now I wanted to get the data in the streaming buffer to troubleshoot this. According to the Bigquery documentation the way to do this is to use `_partitionTime IS NULL`, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    `project.dataset.Jobs` WHERE _partitionTime IS NULL
```

This query ALWAYS returns **an empty result**

[image]

Any ideas for how I can see the data in the streaming buffer?