# How does BigQuery table works with Partition and Cluster field?

Tags: google-bigquery

When specifying `TIMESTAMP` column as partition - The data is saved on the disk by the partition allows each access.

Now, BigQuery allows to also define up to 4 columns which will used as cluster field.

If I get it correctly the partition is like `PK` and the cluster fields are like `indexes`.

So this means that the cluster fields has nothing to do with how records are saved on the disk?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209597/1031958) which provides a good answer around this subject. Also [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b) medium post is very good by @Felipe

Comment: @TamirKlein it doesn't. It talks about clustering fields regardless of partition field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I get it correctly the partition is like PK

This is not correct, Partition is not used to identify a row in the table rather enable BigQuery to Store each partitioned data in a different segment so when you scan a table by Partition you ONLY scan the specified partitions and thus reduce your scanning cost

> cluster fields are like indexes

This is correct cluster fields are used as pointers to records in the table and enable quick/minimal cost access to data regardless to the partition. This means Using cluster fields you can query a table cross partition with minimal cost

I like @Felipe image from [his medium post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b) which gives nice visualization on how data is stored.

Note: Partitioning happens on the time of the insert while clustering happens as a background job performed by BigQuery

[image]